# Sharepoint application with offline support

Tags: development, synchronisation, workspace, offline

I want to create an application (C#) that can work with Sharepoint in offline mode (read/add/modify documents) and sync with the server whenever a connection is established.

What is the best solution for this? anything existing? (framework? application?)

Answer (score 2):

Office OOTB SP Workspace (former Groove) is the first option (edit - unfortunately there is no SharePoint support in Workspace API so far :( ) http://blogs.msdn.com/b/sharepoint_workspace_development_team/archive/2010/08/06/groove-web-services-api-available-in-sharepoint-workspace-2010.aspx. Another option is completely custom application with own data layer and OM, preferably matching SP one. The most tricky part will be dealing with conflicts, all other stuff could be coveres by SP Web Services/.NET Client Object Model.

Comment: Do Sp workspace expose its API's so i can use them?

Comment: Do Sp workspace expose its API's so i can use them? coz it seems u can only connect to Groove workspace with the webservices and not to SharePoint workspace.

Comment: yes you can use Groove WS to work with SharePoint workspace; actually SP Workspace is just a next version of Groove Workspace

Comment: Can you give me more details please, or a sample piece of code on how to use , i've been reading the http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb290958.aspx release note of Groove WS and it is mentioned clearly "There is no Groove Web Services access to SharePoint workspaces", access is only avaiable to Groove Workspace and Shared Folders, but not SharePoint Workspaces. thanks

Comment: sorry, there was mess with product name (SharePoint Workspace) and actual workspace type (SharePoint Workspace vs Groove Workspace). You right, no way to use Groove SDK with SP Workspace but you can build your app based on Groove type of workspace Add-In but customize it to work with SharePoint. This gives you offline sync capabilities but bring all responsibilities for data access and logic on you.

Answer (score 0):

May be you can use SharePoint Workspace

Comment: Do Sp workspace expose its API's so i can use them?